# How to rename a file with non-ASCII character encoding to ASCII

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, ascii, filenames

I have the file name, "abc枚.xlsx", containing some kind of non-ASCII character encoding and I'd like to remove all non-ASCII characters to rename it to "abc.xlsx".

Here is what I've tried:

```
import os
import string
os.chdir(src_dir)  #src_dir is a path to my directory that contains the odd file
for file_name in os.listdir(): 
    new_file_name = ''.join(c for c in file_name if c in string.printable)
    os.rename(file_name, new_file_name)
```

The following error results at `os.rename()`:

```
builtins.WindowsError: (2, 'The system cannot find the file specified')
```

This is on a Windows system, `sys.getfilesystemencoding()` gives me `mbcs`, if that helps any.

What should I do to circumvent this error and allow me to change the file name?

Comment: This is Python 3.X, correct?  (`os.listdir()` throws an exception on 2.X, unless you pass it a path)

Comment: Try converting the original filename to Unicode. Your loop will break a multi-byte character into single bytes, and some of them may be invalid filename characters even if they're printable.

Comment: @MarkRansom: `file_name` should be already Unicode string (optional path equals to `'.'` (Unicode string) therefore `listdir()` must return Unicode strings).

Comment: show `print(ascii(file_name), ascii(new_file_name))` that cause the error.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian the OP hasn't verified that this is Python 3 yet.

Comment: @MarkRansom: path is optional for `listdir()` in Python 3.2+ only.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is Python 3.2.

Answer (score 12):

Here you go, this works with python 2.7 as well

```
import os
import string

for file_name in os.listdir(src_dir): 
    new_file_name = ''.join(c for c in file_name if c in string.printable)
    os.rename(os.path.join(src_dir,file_name), os.path.join(src_dir, new_file_name))
```

Cheers! Don't forget to up-vote if you find this answer useful! ;)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not yet able to do this with proper utf-8 and regular expression, but at least it worked.